# select *.jpg file Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, directory, nsfilemanager

I am looking for a simple way in Objective-C to select all of the .jpg files in a directory. Right now I can only get all of the directory contents. Is there a way to apply a wildcard, like *.jpg, to the results?

```
 if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:@"/folder2/"] )
             [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:@"/folder2/" toPath:@"/folder1/" error:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like:

```
NSArray *list = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/folder2/" error:nil];
for (NSString* file in list) {
    if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"jpg"]) {
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:file toPath:@"/folder1/" error:nil];
    }
}
```

The `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error` method returns an array containing the names of the files in the specified directory. For each entry, the result of the `NSString` `pathExtension` method is compared against the target string ("jpg"). Any matching files are copied into the destination directory.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much straight from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/enumeratorAtPath%3a):

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:docsDir];
NSString *file;
while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
    if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"jpg"]) {
        // process the document
        [self doSomethingWithFile: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]];
    }
}
```

It looks like NSDirectoryEnumerator also supports fast enumeration, so you could use that instead:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:docsDir];
for (NSString *file in dirEnum) {
    if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"doc"]) {
        // process the document
        [self doSomethingWithFile: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]];
    }
}
```

The difference between using a directory enumerator and iterating over the list returned by `-contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:` is that the directory enumerator will also provide results from subdirectories.

Comment: I considered copying the same example. But this would do a deep search, which doesn't quite match wildcard semantics.